# turtlebot_gazebo crashes when launched

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm having a problem in my laptop when launching turtlebot gazebo as follows (previously running roscore):

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

All the initialization is right, but just when the interface is displayed, the following message is showed in the terminal:

```
Warning [parser.cc:356] No <sdf> element in file[data-string]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 31742, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver /opt/ros/hydro/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/raul/.ros/log/f0a1a0a2-5428-11e3-899f-00234d4cde76/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/raul/.ros/log/f0a1a0a2-5428-11e3-899f-00234d4cde76/gazebo-1*.log
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 31747, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/raul/.ros/log/f0a1a0a2-5428-11e3-899f-00234d4cde76/gazebo_gui-2.log].
log file: /home/raul/.ros/log/f0a1a0a2-5428-11e3-899f-00234d4cde76/gazebo_gui-2*.log
```

Unfortunately, the referred logs doesn't exist. My setup is:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- ros-hydro-full-desktop

I've not performed any modification to turtlebot and its config files.

Any idea about what could be happening? A clue would be very apreciated! I need to work with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104236/turtlebot_gazebo-crashes-when-launched/) by [jotaraul](https://answers.ros.org/users/9056/jotaraul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I tried unistalling the fglrx driver of my ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3450, and it works.

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1634/gazebo-gui-crashed-immediately-on-start/?answer=1977#post-id-1977

---

Originally posted by [jotaraul](https://answers.ros.org/users/9056/jotaraul/) with karma: 46 on 2013-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [greenhand](https://answers.ros.org/users/13721/greenhand/) on 2014-03-24**:
I can run successfully except turtlebot_gazebo launch file,is there any problem with the package?